# Probability of only getting k consecutive successes?

Tags: probability

The question I'm trying to solve is the following.

Independent trials, each resulting in success with probability p, are performed until $k$ consecutive successful trials have occurred. Let $X$ be the total number of successes in these trials, and let $P_n = P(X = n)$. Find $P_k$.

The way I understand the question is that I need to find the probability that, if we perform $m$ trials, there will be $k$ successes, and they will be consecutive.

So I did the following:

$$
P_k = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=k|F=i)P(F=i)
$$
F is the number of failures at the beginning.
$$
P_k = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)P(F=i)
$$
$$
P_k = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^k(1-p)^i
$$
$$
P_k = p^k\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^i
$$
$$
P_k = \frac{p^k}{1-p}
$$

However, the answer is $p^{k-1}$ and I'm struggling to understand why.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You seem to describe three different problems here. The title says you want to find the probability of getting *only* k successes, the next description describes a geometric random variable, and your interpretation introduces a variable $m$ that was not defined or described. You'll need to clarify the problem if you hope to get a good answer. Best of luck!

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  A [very similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631912/probability-of-n-total-successes-in-a-series-of-trials-that-ends-after-the-first) was asked a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way $X$ could be $k$ is if the string of outcomes had the form $F^mS^k$ where $F$ denotes Fail, $S$ denotes Success, and $m$ could be any non-negative number.

Now $P(F^mS^k)=(1-p)^mp^k$ so $$P(X=k)=p^k\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^m=p^k\times \frac 1{1-(1-p)}=p^{k-1}$$as desired.

Answer (score 2):

To get $X=k$:

- you need to have the first success preceded by any non-negative number of failures (with probability $1$ that you reach this state at some stage)
- followed immediately by $k-1$ more successes, so with probability $p^{k-1}$.